# Terraform Import - finding the resource id

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-elasticache

I am trying to import an `aws_db_subnet_group`. The [terraform docs](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/db_subnet_group.html) are very limited in explaining how you are supposed to go about doing this other than providing the one line to execute

```
terraform import aws_db_subnet_group.default <subnet-group-id>
```

I am searching the AWS console and I cannot find this `<subnet-group-id>` anywhere. I've ran into this issue a few times now, hunting through the AWS console for a specific resource's ID so that I can import it. Does anyone know where/how to go about doing this in general? And for my current problem, how to find it for an ElastiCache Subnet Group ID?

I referred to the [aws elasticache](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/elasticache/index.html) documentation and tried running `describe-cache-subnet-groups`

```
aws elasticache describe-cache-subnet-groups --cache-subnet-group-name <name>
```

But this did not give me any ID related to the cache subnet group that I could use for the import

Answer (score 2):

First of all, DB subnet groups and ElastiCache subnet groups are two different things. You don't use your db subnet groups for your ElasticCache instances.

From the documentation it seems that both db subnet groups and cache subnet groups are imported by their names, not IDs. You can find your subnet group names in your console:

`ElastiCache` dashboard - `Subnet Groups` on the sidebar - `Name` column

or `RDS` dashboard - `Subnet Groups` on the sidebar - `Name` column

Comment: The first part of what you said makes sense. It could be weirdness in a terraform naming convention, or that I was trying to import the wrong resource. At any rate, I had the luxury in this scenario of being able to delete the cache subnet group. When I did this, the next `terraform apply` went smoothly. Thanks for the response!